Automorphism group of $x^3 - x - y^2$.
Let $k$ be some field of characteristic $\neq 2$. The polynomial $f(x,y) = x^3 - x - y^2$ is irreducible in $k[x,y] \cong k[x][y]$ as it cannot have a root in $k[x]$. By Gauss's lemma, $f$ is then also irreducible in $k(x)[y]$. The ideal it generates is maximal, and we can consider the field $E := k(x)[y]/(f)$. Now, $E/k(x)$ ist Galois of degree $2$. Setting $\alpha := y + (f)$, we may write $E = \\{g(x) + h(x)\alpha \mid g,h \in k(x)\\}$. The Galois group $H := \operatorname{Gal}(E/k(x))$ consists of the identity and the automorphism $\sigma$ that sends $\alpha$ to $-\alpha$. It is well-known that the elements of $L := \operatorname{Aut}_k(k(x))$ send $$x \mapsto \frac{a + bx}{c + dx}, \quad a,b,c,d \in k, \quad ad - bc \neq 0.$$ The automorphism group $L$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{PGL}_2(k)$.
Question: What can be said about $G := \operatorname{Aut}_k(E)$?
We have $H$ as a subgroup of $G$ and can define an injective group homomorphism $$s: L = \operatorname{Aut}_k(k(x)) \to G=\operatorname{Aut}_k(E), \quad \tau \mapsto \tilde\tau,$$ by $\tilde\tau(x) = \tau(x)$ and $\tilde\tau(\alpha) = \alpha$, so we can consider $L$ a subgroup of $G$ as well. Now it would be nice if $\theta(x) \in k(x)$ for all $\theta \in G$ so that $\theta$ could be restricted to an automorphism of $k(x)$, because then $G = H \rtimes L$, but I have no idea why that should be the case.

To answer your question the automorphism group of $E$ is generated by $E(k)$ itself -- the group of $k$-rational points on $E$ -- and two natural involutions of $E$ (one you give, try spot the other). This follows from results in chapter 3 of Silverman's book on elliptic curves (in particular every morphism of elliptic curves is a composition of an isogeny and a translation, then using the fact that birational maps of smooth projective curves are morphims
